# Grails , resolve conflict between migration plugin and searchable plugin

Tags: spring, grails

I am using both  migration plugin (**version 1.3.8**) and searchable plugin (**version 0.6.5**) on grails (**version 2.3.0**) but I can not manage making the searchable plugin run after the migration plugin.

I searched and found this as a solution:

adding this to ***config.groovy***

```
bulkIndexOnStartup = false
mirrorChanges = false
```

and adding this to ***bootstrap.groovy***

```
searchableService.reindex()
searchableService.startMirroring()
```

but **this is not helping.**

This is the error I get:

```
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column 'this_.address' in 'field list'
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:386)

.
.
.
Error executing script DbmGormDiff: org.compass.gps.CompassGpsException: Failed to index, execution exception; nested exception is java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.compass.gps.device.hibernate.HibernateGpsDeviceException: {hibernate}: Failed to index the database; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute query using scroll (Use --stacktrace to see the full trace)
```

thanks,

Comment: This might be a little too late for OP, but in case others encounter this issue ... I modified the two config properties in Searchable.groovy instead of Config.groovy and was able to avoid the "unknown column" error. My guess is that if you didn't make the edits to Searchable.groovy, then the default properties in Searchable.groovy would override the properties set in Config.groovy.

Answer (score 0):

Just till I get a permanent solution I did this.

***1. comment out the searchable plugin in buildConfig.groovy*** ( It will be automatically uninstalled when you run the next grails command)

***2. Do whatever you want to do with the migration plugin***

***3. uncomment the searchable plugin in buildConfig.groovy*** (It will be automatically installed when you run the next grails command)

but still curios to know why doing:

```
bulkIndexOnStartup = false
mirrorChanges = false
```

is not disabling the plugin till bootstrap